# Filtering on a non-field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search (2.4)

For simplicity, here is my example.

I want to get a list of all players on level 2

`{"player":"X", "level":2}`

I want to use `include` on `level`, but display the field 'name`

```
{
  "_source" : {
    "game" : "XYZ",
    "stats" : [ {
      "level" : 2,
      "player" : "Bob"
    }, {
      "level" : 1,
      "player" : "Peter"
    }],
  }
}
```

I added my mapping to show my data:

```
{
  "tasks" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "task_document" : {
        "properties" : {
          "game" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "stats" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "player" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "level" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1491798329041",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "Yxxx",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2040299"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of my attempt which rendered no results:

```
      "aggs": {
    "inner": {
      "aggs": {
        "stats.player_L2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "player",
            "include": {"stats.level":2}
            "size": 50
          }
        },
        "stats.player_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "player"
          }
        }
      },
      "nested": {
        "path": "stats"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I also tired to filter on the path by doing:

```
  "nested": {
    "path": "stats",
    "filter":{"term":
      {
      "stats.level":2
      }
    }
```

That gives the error: `nested: SearchParseException[Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [inner].]` for my attempt`

What is the correct query to get JUST results of level 2 AND return the field PLAYER?

EDIT: Added my mapping

Comment: if you just want to fetch player names at level 2 why are you running aggregations?

Comment: its getting confusing, can you also add a json for your desired results

Comment: Because I will show multiple `level` lists. EG listing players on level 1, then players on level 2. i've updated my OP with mapping.

Comment: @Ycon Did you try `inner_hits` [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) option?

Comment: No, please show an example of how to use it

Comment: e.g `GET my_index/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "stats",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "stats.level": 2 }} 
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": false,
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "stats.player": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: But I don't want to filter the entire query, I only want to filter the result of `stats.player_L1`, then 'stats.player_L2` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "inner": {
      "aggs": {
        "stats.player_L2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "stats.level",
            "include": "2",
            "size": 50
          },
          "aggs": {
            "names": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "stats.player_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "stats.player"
          }
        }
      },
      "nested": {
        "path": "stats"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error "Could not find aggregator type `[stats.player_L2]` in [aggs]"

Comment: What is the exact query you used?

Comment: I removed the "inner" as that gave an error regarding nesting. http://dpaste.com/02S2DST. Keep in mind my values inside `stats` are nested within `[ ]`

Comment: Why did you do that? `inner` is the name of the aggregation and it should be there. What error did you initially get with the `inner` in there?

Comment: When I keep `inner`, I get the error `[nested] nested path [stats] is not nested`

Comment: The query refers to `stats` field, not `player` (the one from your errors). According to the mapping you provided `stats` is a `nested` field and this is what I used (and you did as well) in my query.

Comment: That was a mis-type, It said `[nested] nested path [stats] is not nested`

Comment: Still, my comment stands: the mapping you provided shows `stats` as `nested` field. So, you either changed the mapping in the meantime, or the mapping you provided is not accurate.

Comment: Yes, and this is why I posted. I continually get that error. Here is an exact paste of my ES result- http://dpaste.com/2JMX6H3

Comment: I'm trying to help you here, but please understand that what you initially asked and what you are reporting back now doesn't make sense. Please, use the same mapping from your post with my query and try again. Otherwise, I'm afraid I cannot help you. The query I provided is tested and it works.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt, but how is my mapping different from my initial question? I simple gave what comes inside the `_source` object. Will I ask a new question?