# ElasticSearch nesting for varied value

Tags: elasticsearch

Im looking for a clean solution for this. Basically I have arrays which are numbered by an integer. This number may be from 1-50. Rather than repeating my index 50 times, is there a work around for this?

Here is an example of how I would do it for level `1`.

Thanks

```
"test" : {
            "properties" : {
              "1" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "taglevel" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "2" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "taglevel" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "3" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "taglevel" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  }
                }
              },
```

## repeat 47 times more until

```
  "50" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "taglevel" : {
        "type" : "long"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the requirement. Can you re-formulate?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Pl, I've just reformulated the example, should be pretty clear I hope

Comment: Ok. So you have 50 fields in your index, what exactly you don't want to repeat? Is this a dynamic mapping or not?

Comment: I dont want to have to specify the number, as I want to allow for it to be above `50`. Like it would be good to use a * indicating any number

Comment: Elasticsearch cannot choose the field names for you. You'd have to do this before you index the documents.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's the answer. ElasticSearch is not capable of this. In that case, I really need to understand how to filter inside a nest. I created a question here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316959. Thanks